# Laravel: htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, with anchor tag text?

Tags: laravel

First time using Laravel and i've downloaded a project.  I get this error **htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given**  I've found it is due to the following:

```
@guest
<li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="{{ route('login') }}">{{ __('Login') }}</a></li>
@if (Route::has('register'))
    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="{{ route('register') }}">{{ __('Register') }}</a></li>
@endif
```

If i remove `{{ __('Login') }}` and `{{ __('Register') }}` the error is removed and i can view the page?   How do i solve?  What could be the reason for this error?

Comment: The value of `__('Login')`, which is a translation, is not a `string`; it's likely an array or object. You'll have to include the code you used to define those translation objects (likely a file or files in `resources/lang/{code}/`)

Comment: So i've found `resources/lang/en/` and it has multiple files.  All files return an array.    Do i add this to array `'login' => 'Login','register' => 'Register'`?

Comment: thanks, that solved it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is saying that `__('Login')` is not a `string`. This means that it likely is an array of translation keys, as `__()` by default returns a `string` (the passed parameter) if the translation is not available.

Inside of `resources/lang/{lang}`, there is a file called `login.php`:

```
return [
  'login' => 'Login',
  'register' => 'Register'
];
```

To access this translation, you need to use the correct syntax:

```
<li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="{{ route('login') }}">{{ __('login.login') }}</a></li>
<li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="{{ route('register') }}">{{ __('login.register') }}</a></li>
```

The string passed to the `__()` function should first specify the file, followed by any number of keys (as nested arrays are valid). In both cases, `login` is the file, followed by the keys `login` and `register`.

This structure should be duplicated in all `resources/lang/{lang}/login.php` files, or the default locale (in most cases `en`) will be used.

The full documentation can be found here: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/localization